# Objective-C:How to read an attribute value in XML

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xml

Hi friends am new to iphone app developing. Actually i have to parse XML file and have display it in a tableviewcontroller. Am using storyboards. i have parsed Xml successfully and parsed data and displayed it. But i cannot able to read this attribute `<Event count="-1">` i have read this value and have to display it on the tab bar i have to set badge value as -1
Pls help me How to do it. Thanks in advance.. Here is my Xml file

```
<boards>
<board count="-1">
<newboard>
<id>9</id>
<invitationdet>qweq</invitationdet>
<readflag>1</readflag>
<responseflag>1</responseflag>
</newboard>
<newboard>
<id>8</id>
<invitationdet>asd</invitationdet>
<readflag>1</readflag>
<responseflag>1</responseflag>
</newboard>
</board>
<back count="0">
<backboard>
<id>2</id>
<feedbackdet>Meeting with Clients</feedbackdet>
<readflag>1</readflag>
<responseflag>0</responseflag>
</backboard>
<backboard>
<id>1</id>
<feedbackdet>Board Meeting with employees</feedbackdet>
<readflag>1</readflag>
<responseflag>0</responseflag>
</backboard>
</back>
<letter count="3">
<newletter>
<id>4</id>
<letterdet>NewsLetter for the month of October 2013</letterdet>
<readflag>1</readflag>
</newletter>
<newletter>
<id>3</id>
<letterdet>Newsletter for the month of September 2013</letterdet>
<readflag>0</readflag>
</newletter>
<newletter>
<id>2</id>
<letterdet>Newsletter for the month of August 2013</letterdet>
<readflag>0</readflag>
</newletter>
<newletter>
<id>1</id>
<letterdet>Newsletter For the month of July 2013</letterdet>
<readflag>0</readflag>
</newletter>
</letter>
</boards>
```

And Here is my XMLParser File

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"boards"]) {
        rssOutputData  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"board"]) {
        //Initialize the array.

        aEvent.count = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"count"];
         NSLog(@"Reading count value :%@", aEvent.count);
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"newboard"]) {
        //Initialize the book.
        aEvent = [[Eventlist alloc] init];
        //Extract the attribute here.
        aEvent.id = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"userid"] integerValue];
        NSLog(@"Reading id value :%d", aEvent.id);
    }
    NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if(!nodecontent)
        nodecontent = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];else
            [nodecontent appendString:string];
    NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", nodecontent);
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"boards"])
        return;
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"board"])
        return;
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"newboard"]) {
        [rssOutputData addObject:aEvent];
        [aEvent release];
        aEvent= nil;
        }
    else
        [aEvent setValue:nodecontent forKey:elementName];
    [nodecontent release];
    nodecontent = nil;

}
```

I can read datas correctly but i cannot able to read Attribute values pls help me friends

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project take alook

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try like the below

```
 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
    didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
      namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
     qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
        attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
    {
        // just do this for item elements
        if(![elementName isEqual:@"letter"])
            return;

        // then you just need to grab each of your attributes
        int count  = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"count"];


    }
```

Comment: why down-voting . it helps a user and solves his problem then why down-voting

Answer (score -1):

In the following method you have noticed that, there is a parameter `attributeDict` which holds all the attributes of tag

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([attributeDict valueForKey:@"count"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [attributeDict valueForKey:@"count"]);
    }
}
```

You can read it as defined in the above code. just log whole `attributeDict` and you will get your answer. - Good Luck